# No output from Html.ActionLink when trying to check Controller name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This is probably a simple oversight but I'm not seeing the problem so I thought I'd ask for some quick help. I'm somewhat new to MVC also (and Razor) so that might have something to do with it also. Basically, here's what's in my Razor View that renders some list items for a navigation bar. I'm just trying to set a class of "selected" on the element if (according to the Controller name) it's the page being requested.

```
<li>@{ if(Html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == "AdminHome")
         {
               Html.ActionLink("Admin Home", "Index", "AdminHome", null, new { @class = "selected" });
            }
            else{
                Html.ActionLink("Admin Home", "Index", "AdminHome");
            }
         }
</li>
```

The result I'm getting is just an empty list item element:  `<li></li>`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Is it just a syntax issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prefix `@` before `Html.ActionLink`. Otherwise MVC treats this as a ordinary method call not a method that outputs `html`.

```
<li>
@if(Html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == "AdminHome"){
      @Html.ActionLink("Admin Home", "Index", "AdminHome", null, new { @class = "selected" });
}
else{
      @Html.ActionLink("Admin Home", "Index", "AdminHome");
}

</li>
```

Comment: Thanks - that's all it was. I didn't realize it still needed the @ character before it since it was within a @{ } block. Your explanation of it differentiating html output vs. just a ordinary method call was actually news to me since I'm still a bit of a Razor newbie.

Answer (score 0):

compare the route name in case insensitve like 
String.Equals(Html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() , "AdminHome",,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
because route name can be in any case. It is what user has typed in url.
For example in url
www.yourdomain.com/AdminHome/Index (controller name is AdminHome and controller will be AdminHomeController)
but with url 
www.yourdomain.com/adminhome/index (controller name is adminhome and controller will be AdminHomeController)

Hope this helps.